What is fourfold restraint?
I read this:

One time, sir, I approached Nigaṇṭha Nātaputta and exchanged greetings
with him. When the greetings and polite conversation were over, I sat
down to one side, and asked him the same question.
He said: ‘Great king, consider a Jain ascetic who is restrained in the
fourfold restraint. And how is a Jain ascetic restrained in the
fourfold restraint? It’s when a Jain ascetic is obstructed by all
water, devoted to all water, shaking off all water, pervaded by all
water. That’s how a Jain ascetic is restrained in the fourfold
restraint. When a Jain ascetic is restrained in the fourfold
restraint, they’re called a knotless one who is self-realized,
self-controlled, and steadfast.’
And so, when I asked Nigaṇṭha Nāṭaputta about the fruits of the
ascetic life apparent in the present life, he answered with the
fourfold restraint.

Is water symbolic and heavenly? What are some other ways to describe fourfold restraint b/c the description sounds like a haiku, poetic and koan-like, "devoted to water", so I just wonder b/c if water means 'cosmic water' then perhaps this is similar to a jhanic-transcendental-state? But has anyone who has jhana experienced 'cosmic water'?
I recall reading:
“eleven [rudras] are seated on waters”
" Nårāyana lay asleep on the cosmic waters at that time "

alternate text: "There is the case where the Nigaṇṭha is obstructed by all waters, conjoined with all waters, cleansed with all waters, suffused with all waters."

idk, but this is probably just metaphor, not 'cosmic water', just water as related to the burning fires and embers of desire
